# Altair: Use variable color schemes for selected columns

Tags: color-scheme, vega, altair

I have a GeoDataFrame with 3 different value columns, that can be selected separately by drop down. Currently for all 3 selected columns the color scheme of the chart is "blues". However, I would like to choose the color scheme more flexible, so that each column has a different scheme, for example ['blues','greens','purples'].

I have been trying to solve this with nested conditions, encodings and transform_calculate conditions, but without success.
Is this somehow possible to realize?

[image]

```
columns = ['BinPer', 'DinPer', 'BEVinPer']
select_box = alt.binding_select(options=columns, name='column')
sel = alt.selection_single(fields=['column'], bind=select_box, init={'column': 'BinPer'}, 
                           clear=False,
                           on="click[event.shiftKey&!event.shiftKey]")

map_ = alt.Chart(source).transform_fold(
    columns,
    as_=['column', 'value']
).transform_filter(
    sel
).mark_geoshape(
    stroke='white',
    strokeWidth=0.5
).encode(     
    color = alt.Color('value:Q', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='blues'))
).add_selection(
    sel
)
map_
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to vary the color scheme within a single chart based on the value selected from a built-in dropdown menu.

If you want to do something like this, the best option would probably be to use a tool like [ipywidgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/) to define the dropdown menu, and output a chart with the desired color scheme for each value.